# Как обратиться к классу из класса, расположенного во вложенном пакете java

Tags: java

Есть классы `eugene.Main.java` и `eugene.entity.User.java`. Как из `User` обратиться к `Main`?

Comment: Раскройте что вы имеете в виду под "обратиться". Если вызвать статический метод - это легко и просто через имя делается. Если нестатические методы вызвать, нестатические переменные получить - надо долго и нудно фигачить сложную архитектуру, инъекции зависимостей там всякие или синглтон фигачить или просто ссылку передать... Невозможно вам в вашей формулировке вопроса ответ дать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего через импорт

**Main.java**

```
package ru.demo;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    }  
    public static void printHello() {
        System.err.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
package ru.demo.exts;
import ru.demo.Main;
public class Demo {
    public Demo() {
        Main.printHello();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если экземпляр `eugene.entity.User.java` создается в `Main.java`, то создавать его надо так:

```
User user = new User(this);
```

а в `eugene.entity.User.java` нужен конструктор

```
private Main main;
public User(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}
```

Теперь в `eugene.entity.User.java` можно обращаться к `Main` через переменную `main`